# rotating HTML Table cells 180 degree

Tags: html, css

for example I have the table below and want to rotate it like the other table.
how can I do this? is there anyway without javascript?

before rotation

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            A
        </td>
        <td>
            B
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            C
        </td>
        <td>
            D
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

after rotation

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            B
        </td>
        <td>
            A
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            D
        </td>
        <td>
            C
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Visually

```
A B        B A
C D  --->  D C
```

Comment: That is not "rotating the table 180 degrees"... that is "rotating *each table row* by 180 degrees".

Comment: That doesn't look like a *rotation* to me, it's a mirror image.  A 2x2 table rotated should end up with at least one of `C` or `D` on the top row.

Comment: Without javascript you will need to enforce this serverside, or write in flash/silverlight.

Comment: You basically want to reverse the order of each table row. You will definitely need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a CSS3 transform:

```css
​table, td {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
       -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
         -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
}​
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gE5sV/

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

As you can see from the above link, CSS3 transforms don't work in IE8 and older. You *can* do it using `filter`, but it will make the text look *really bad*, so I don't recommend it:

```css
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-1,M12=0,M21=0,M22=1,SizingMethod='auto expand');
```